# .htaccess extensionless URLs + ErrorDocument 404 issue

Tags: .htaccess

I use the following code to serve extensionless URLS.  By that I mean anyone requesting myfile.php will be served myfile

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I also use the following so I can use a custom 404 page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

All that works fine until someone types in an extentionless URL which doesn't exist, such as "/abcdefghijkl" In this case Apache returns a blank page with "File not found" which isn't very helpful to users!  In such a case, I want the error page (error.php) to be displayed.  Is it possible?

Comment: Does `example.com/error.php` work fine from browser?

Comment: Yes it resolves correctly.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Don’t check if the requested filename was not a file, check if the requested file name plus `.php` _is_ an existing file.